# How to fix missing values problem in NHMM?

Tags: r, error-handling, missing-data

```
# devtools::install_github("cran/NHMM")
library(NHMM)
gfs.nhmm <- NHMM(y = obs_daily_train, X = atmvar_mme, K = 6, 
  iters = 1000,  burnin = 100, emdist = "gamma", nmix = 1, 
  delta = TRUE, outdir = paste(outdir_MME, "/", sep = ""), 
  ypred = ypred.gfs, Xp = xp.mme)
```

This is a part of NHMM code. After 8% an error encountered:

```
in if (sum(pro) == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Called from: Cgetz(z, QQ, denzity, subseqy)

After debugging, I got Pro in num[1:6]: NaN 2.554379e-127 NaN NaN NaN  0.000000e+00
```

Previously I ran with 3 hourly data and NHMM ran successfully. But it's not happening with daily data. I have no NA, NaN or infinite values in my data. Datasets have no characters. But Pro vector containing NaN values. How to solve it?

Expected completion of the code without error. You will get outputs in text files. The excel datasheets are shared in the below google drive link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A9Degowc9tSOYH4BrfOIlSj2Oo28kEk3/view?usp=sharing. Compiled the code in a text file embedded within this shared archive file. Before running code please follow the instructions mentioned there. You can download this archive and extract on your PC Desktop with same folder name so that you don't have to change the data path.

Comment: Hi Sanghita! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you include some of your data (enough that I can reproduce the problem)? You can use `dput()`

Comment: Can you come on gmeet or any other meeting platform so that I can show you the problem? My gmail id: sanghitabasu50@gmail.com. Because sharing data is restricted.

Comment: in that case, you can create similar data using random sampling or creating data programatically

Comment: But how will I send you the data and code?

Comment: add it to your question

Comment: the thing about StackOverflow is, someone else is likely to have the same problem at some point in the future. It's good to make it so they can get what is going on

Comment: Please find the link for the data used and the code mentioned in the question posted.